# Access to Google fit works in local test app, but not via Google Play

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, cordova-plugins, google-fit

I'm writing a health app, which also uses Google Fit API to read the step counter.
The App is developed with Cordova, with cordova-plugin-health
The App uses an OAuthClient-ID generated with https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1 and works as expected, when installed locally.
But when I install my App via Google Play, I don't get the stepcounter info
(no error messages). I checked the SHA1-signature in Google console.

1) any suggestions why my App is not working when installed via Google Play?

2) do You know any alternatives to Google Fit API? I would prefer to use my app offline, therefore regular access to Google's web service is not ideal

Comment: All modern android devices have an accelerometer built in, and some use that to emulate a "step counter" sensor. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-stepcounter for more info

Answer (score 1):

Because the App you registered is with the debug SHA1 key. To make the app work from PlayStore you need to also register the app using the release SHA1 key.

You must have used,

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

But you need to use,

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

Comment: I registered the release SHA1 key, but it still did not work